# Is there a way I can configure esp32 as a broker

Tags: embedded, esp32, esp-idf, espressif-idf, esp-idf-sys

I want to configure an esp32 as a MQTT broker and connect other devices as clients is there any way to do this. i searched the internet but couldn't find any reliable answer and tried chatgpt it says it can't be done due to, esp32 does not have built-in support for acting as an MQTT broker. The MQTT protocol is typically used for IoT devices to communicate with a central MQTT broker, which then distributes the messages to the appropriate subscribers.

Comment: MQTT is much involved in terms of memory and other requirements than an ESP32 can handle, you probably can do that, but won't be the right device for the job when you considering the network traffic, storage and routing. If you want to have a broker, get a Raspberry Pi which run linux and you can then run mosquitto broker on it.

Answer (score 0):

#include "EmbeddedMqttBroker.h
This ESP32 platform broker works, but in seeing some memory issues.
Im looking at offloading the MQTT data off to an SD card instead of holding messages in memory.